# video is not playing in media player in website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I want to play the video in the media player in my website. For that I placed the media player in my form and I have set the MovieURL.

```
MovieURL=@"C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\video\Wildlife.wmv";
```

But when I run my website on localhost the media player is not running, it also not giving any type of error.

Comment: set LoadedBehavior property to Play and try

Comment: hi manish, I have check for that but there is no such property is available for media player control..